# Adding React-Redux to a helper function

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I have a helper function which is utilized by two components in my React app. And this helper function dispatches a set of Redux actions. How do I connect React-Redux to this helper function so that it can dispatch actions?

My helper looks like this:

```
export default const helper = () => {
   //dispatch some actions
   // I would like to do something similar to  this: this.props.dispatch()
   //do something else(produce some JSX)
}
```

My component look like this:

```
 import helper from './helper.js';

 export default class Example extends React.Component {
   return (
      {helper()}
   );
 }
```

My component **1** look like this when the helper is defined inside the component itself:

```
 import { setTime } from '../actions/setTime.js';

 class Example1 extends React.Component {
   helper() {
     //actions are synchronous
     this.props.setTime('10:00PM');

     return (<h1>hello</h1>);
   }

   render() {
     return (
      <h1>something</h1>
      {helper()}
     );
   }
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      setTime: (time) => (dispatch(setTime(time)))
   };
 }

 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Example1);
```

My component **2** look like this when the helper is defined inside the component itself:

```
 import { setTime } from '../actions/setTime.js';

 class Example2 extends React.Component {
   helper() {
     //actions are synchronous
     this.props.setTime('10:00PM');

     return (<h1>hello</h1>);
   }

   render() {
     return (
      {helper()}
     );
   }
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      setTime: (time) => (dispatch(setTime(time)))
   };
 }

 export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Example2);
```

**Example1 and Example2 renders based on Route change. You might be thinking I can use the higher order component but I cannot because these two components have different state and renders different things.**

Please note that I want to have access to the dispatch function in the helper method and I am not accessing Redux state from that component so I do not have to worry about state change(mapStateToProps is not in use).

Comment: Without your code, it is hard to say. Is your helper function a dispatcher that you can map to your props? Is it how you should use `connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( Component )` you are asking?

Comment: @Icepickle please see edit

Comment: So you are looking for some way to add `dispatch` to your helper method? You really don't want to dispatch some actions from your rendering method, as it could change the state of your component and create some kind of continuous / endless render -> dispatch -> state update -> render -> dispatch ... If you wish to create jsx based on a certain state, maybe your helper should do only that, and you can pass the current state in?

Comment: @Icepickle Please note I am not accessing Redux state from that component so I do not have to worry about state change(mapStateToProps is not in use). And yes, I want to have access to the dispatch function in the helper method.

Comment: Can you give more input code about what your helper function is doing? I would pass helper as 2 second argument of `connect`, I think that would be the most easy way to do it, your helper function would then get dispatch as a first argument (but then you could dispatch from inside your component instead)

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, I think that would work. Let me try that.

Comment: @Icepickle please see edit

Comment: Can you give a bit more input on what you are trying to achieve with the helper function and what you need the dispatches for?

Comment: @Icepickle the helper is common to two components so I want to move the helper function to a separate module.

Comment: @Icepickle I want the dispatchers in the helper function so that I can dispatch some actions to Redux store to update the Redux state. The Redux state is used by other components, not these two.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what you're doing at this moment?

Comment: @Icepickle everything works fine when the helper function is defined inside the component

Comment: @Icepickle but I decided to move the helper function to a separate module so that the other component also make use of this helper function.

Comment: react-redux `connect` is supposed to be used with components. It relies on component hierarchy. Due to how you use `helper`, you most likely have XY problem that should be solved in another way. `helper` could be a component, or else. You can access `dispatch` directly on a store but this may be not a good idea.

Comment: @estus please upvote the question

Comment: I'll do. Consider explaining in the question why you decided to go with `helper` function instead of `Helper` component. As I mentioned, this seems to be XY problem and possibly the reason why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Icepickle If I use the helper function with connect then I won't be able to send arguments to it.

Comment: @estus It is not a component. It is a function that takes some arguments and It returns an array of JSX elements

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You don't use an array anywhere in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is XY problem.

`react-redux` and `connect` are supposed to be used with components, it relies on component hierarchy (React context) to provide a store to components. `connect` isn't supposed to be used with functions that don't belong to component hierarchy.

It's possible to access `store.dispatch` directly in helper function but this indicates design problem because it's low level API that [isn't supposed to be used directly in React](https://redux.js.org/faq/storesetup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself)

Component composition is idiomatic way to compose functionality in React. `helper` function performs a side effect (dispatches an action) and returns an element. It can be expressed as connected component:

```
const Helper = props => {
 props.setTime('10:00PM');

 return (<h1>hello</h1>);
};


 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      setTime: (time) => (dispatch(setTime(time)))
   };
 }

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Helper);
```

Comment: Can `Helper` return an array rather than a JSX element?

Comment: Do you mean an array of elements? Yes. As any React 16 component.

Comment: How do you distinguish a functional component from a function?

Comment: Possibly, looking at the case sensitive function name or React import statement? @estus

Comment: If a function was designed to work as functional component (accepts `props` object as only param, etc) then it's a component. Yes, you can distinguish it by upper case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, i resolve it by passing `this` to helper function.
If u need to dispatch it by action something like example could help.

```
export default const helper = (that) => {
   return <button onClick={()=>that.props.YourDispatch()}/>
}

import helper from './helper.js';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
   return (
      {helper(this)}
   );
}
```